# Como renombrar un Label o un textbox dentro de un bucle?

Tags: bucles, textbox, label

Como cambiar nombre de Label o TextBox en un blucle? Para alimentar datos de celdas consecutivas

Con mi código no reconoce `Label Nom1.caption` ni la `celda B1`

```
for i = 1 to 25

  "Nom"&i.caption = worksheets("hoja1").range("B&i").value 

Next i
```